# Can't connect to Mongo Atlas anyway

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to connect to mongoDB atlas.But can't do it anyway.I have tried all options that found on the stackoverflow

My server.js is like as below

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

/*
-------------- Mongo db connection -----------
*/
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://tintindenmark@gmail.com:*********@cluster0-f9upb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection
    .once('open', () => console.log('Good to go!'))
    .on('error', (error) => {
        console.warn('Warning', error);
    });
/*
------------------------ Mongo db connection ends ------------------------
*/
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/about', req.query)
  })

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

but i cant do it anyway.I have `whitelisted IP` addresses from atlast clusters.
Also tried without `mongodb+srv`.It didnt worked also

Always i am getting this error`MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-f9upb.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.]`

I also tried `mongodb+srv://tintindenmark@gmail.com:musassmc42@cluster0-f9upb.mongodb.net:27017/test` but it also didn't work

So what else i can do to connect??

My mongoose version is : `5.6.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tintindenmark@gmail.com:musassmc42, this username:password is of your atlas account and not your database.

Created a new user and password for you. Try:
mongodb+srv://testuser:testpassword@cluster0-f9upb.mongodb.net:27017/test

And change all passwords.